# Is it possible to test $resource success and error callbacks in a controller?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I would like to test $resource success and error callbacks in my controller. I don’t want to use $httpBackend as that would be used to test the data service. It seems that there is no way to do it though - the only solution I have found is to use promises instead which I could either resolve or reject. Does this sound right? Anyway, here is what I have at the moment - currently it only tests whether the $resource get() is called:

The controller:

```
angular
  .module('myModule')
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

MyCtrl.$inject = [
  'dataService'
];

function MyCtrl(
  dataService
) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.getData = getData;

  function getData() {
    dataService.getData().get(function(response) {
      // stuff to test
    },

    function(error) {
      // stuff to test
    });
  }
```

The test:

```
describe('Controller: MyCtrl', function() {
  var MyCtrl;
  var rootScope;
  var scope;
  var dataServiceMock =  {
    getData: jasmine.createSpy('getData')
  };

  beforeEach(function() 
    inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
      rootScope = $rootScope;
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      MyCtrl = $controller('MyCtrl as vm', {
        dataService: dataServiceMock,
      });
    });
  });

  describe('vm.getData()', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      dataServiceMock.getData.and.returnValue({
        get: jasmine.createSpy('get')
      });
    });

    it('gets the data', function() {
      scope.vm.getData();
      expect(dataServiceMock.getData().get).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getData (query) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var httpPromise = $resource(query,{},{
            post:{
                method:"GET",
                isArray: false,
                responseType: "json"
            }
        });

        httpPromise.post({}, {},
            function(data) {
                try {
                    var results = {}
                    results.totalItems = data.response;
                    deferred.resolve(results);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error.stack);
                    deferred.reject();
                }
            },
            function(error) {
                deferred.reject();
            }
        );

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I said in my question I am aware that if I use  promises I can test the $resource result - I would ideally like to find a way of being able to test success and error callbacks though to avoid refactoring existing code.